# How to Implement OnPreviewMouseDown without Code-Behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, code-behind

I need to make my code MVVM (Which means **no Code-Behind implantation**), and I want to **change my LabelBackground** on **any click**(even if i click the button).

Which means I need to get rid of my `MainWindowView_OnPreviewMouseDown` and `MainWindowView_OnPreviewMouseUp` from my Code-Behind.

Here is my working project:

***Code-Behind***

```
    public partial class MainWindowView : Window
    {

        private readonly MainWindowViewModel _viewModel;
        public MainWindowView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
            // The DataContext serves as the starting point of Binding Paths
            DataContext = _viewModel;
        }

        private void MainWindowView_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _viewModel.LabelBackground = Brushes.Black;
        }

        private void MainWindowView_OnPreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _viewModel.LabelBackground = Brushes.Blue;
        }
    }
}
```

***XAML***

```
<Window x:Class="WpfExample.MainWindowView" PreviewMouseDown="MainWindowView_OnPreviewMouseDown" PreviewMouseUp="MainWindowView_OnPreviewMouseUp"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfExample">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding HiButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="Hai" Content="click to hi"
                Height="100" Margin="208,30,203,30"  />
        <Label Content="Disco Background" Background="{Binding LabelBackground}" Margin="208,66,203,69" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

***VIEWMODEL***

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ICommand hiButtonCommand;
    public ICommand HiButtonCommand
    {
        get
        { return hiButtonCommand; }
        set
        { hiButtonCommand = value; }
    }

    private SolidColorBrush labelBackground;
    public SolidColorBrush LabelBackground
    {
        get { return labelBackground; }
        set
        {
            if (labelBackground != value)
            {
                labelBackground = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LabelBackground");
            }
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        HiButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowMessage);
    }

    public void ShowMessage(object obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(obj.ToString());
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do that?

**edit:**

> I tried to use `EventTrigger` approach and it doesn't work well for me because
>   it doesn't change the label background, it's changing the background
>   of the window instead. Is there any way to target the label instead of
>   the window?

***XAML:***

```
<Window x:Class="WpfExample.MainWindowView" PreviewMouseDown="MainWindowView_OnPreviewMouseDown" PreviewMouseUp="MainWindowView_OnPreviewMouseUp"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfExample">

    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.PreviewMouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation To="Black" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                    Duration="0"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.PreviewMouseUp">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation To="Blue" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                    Duration="0"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding HiButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="Hai" Content="click to hi" Height="100" Margin="208,30,203,30"/>
        <Label Name="Label" Content="Disco Background" Background="White" Margin="208,66,203,59" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: MVVM is about decoupling the view from the model. It's not about elimination of C# from the view or code-behind. Code-behind is fine but often could and should be avoided when there is a XAML solution since XAML is simple and easy to read (since the markup reflects the visual tree structure). The XAML parser does a lot of work for you, so no need to do things manually using C#. Some things have to be done in code-behind. Most of the logic that is not directly related to the visuals of a control for instance. It's good to avoid code-behind but not always possible.

Comment: Since it is not clear what your handlers are doing I can't address your specific situation. But I can generally address your code example: create the view model instance with XAML and not C#, assign the view model to the `DataContext` in XAML and not C#. Consider using `EventTriggers` to handle routed events like `PreviewMouseDown`.

Comment: I tried to use the `EventTrigger` approach and it doesn't work well for me because it doesn't change the label background, it's changing the background of the window instead. Is there any way to target the label instead of the window? (see edited question) @BionicCode

Comment: Just add the following attached property to each `ColorAnimation`: `Storyboard.TargetName="Label"`

Answer (score 2):

My New XAML Solved the problem
no need for code-behind no more:

**new XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfExample.MainWindowView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfExample">

    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.PreviewMouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation To="Black" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Label"
                                    Duration="0"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.PreviewMouseUp">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation To="Blue" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Label"
                                    Duration="0"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding HiButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="Hai" Content="click to hi" Height="100" Margin="208,30,203,30"/>
        <Label Name="Label" Content="Disco Background" Background="White" Margin="208,66,203,59" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple task and there are no best ways.

1. Use fody https://github.com/Fody/Home/ with property changed https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged
2. Create a base class view that implements notify property changed
3. Use framework that supports MV* patterns like Caliburn.Micro https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/cheat-sheet

and the code should be something in the lines of:

**XAML**

```
<Button 
    cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDown] = [Action Action1]" 
    cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseUp] = [Action Action2]" 
    Content="{Binding ButtonContent}" />
<Label 
    Content="Disco Background" 
    Background="{Binding Importance, Converter={StaticResource ImportanceToBgConverter}}"/>
```

**ViewModel**

```
    public String ButtonContent { get; set; } = "click to hi";
    public ImportanceType Importance { get; set; }
    public void Action1()
    {
        Importance = Importance.NotImportant;
    }

    public void Action2()
    {
        Importance = Importance.Important;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is good MVVM. Colors are view related (in most cases) and should be defined as resources, maybe inside a dedicated assembly. In your example the view model handles UI logic. This violates a clean separation Your example can be easily implemented using an `EventTrigger` in XAML. No need of any framework at this point.

Comment: `PreviewMouseDown` is a routed event for a good reason. It's totally view related and is supposed to be handled in XAML (preferred choice for event handling of routed events are `EventTrigger` handlers).

Comment: @BionicCode this is perfectly fine and you can imagine that instead of hard coded values it reads the values from database, or resource dictionary (just in code). Yes, with data triggers or event triggers you can create a XAML only solution as well and in that case you would usually keep it at within resource files. Generally you would want to change the theme on-fly, a good example how to do this: https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit

Comment: I don't think this is perfectly fine. The view model shouldn't know about which colors the UI elements have. UI should have its colors depend on resource keys. Then on initialization you would add the colors from the database to a `ResourceDictionary`. Each color must therefore map to a resource key. Making the view model responsible for coloring the UI is perfectly wrong. This introduces a coupling that is too tight. Mouse events are UI related and nothing else. Mouse or Keyboard or touch are user input devices intended to interact with the UI and not with the model or view model.

Comment: @BionicCode My point is that with this trivial example i demonstrated how to skip the code behind file and simply bind events to viewmodel methods that he can pass arguments.

Comment: I understand your point. But obviously most people move logic into the wrong place just to keep the code-behind empty. That's cheating. Now the Code-behind is empty but the view model polluted e.g. with event handlers for the views. Empty code-behind over MVVM? I think we need to face the reality which is that sometimes it is not possible to keep the code-behind empty. When it comes to complex logic of a control, then this can't be avoided. WPF native controls show this. Controls like `ItemsControl`or `TextBox`etc. they all need code-behind to realize their complex  (invisible) behavior.